# What replaces Java's sun.security packages?

Tags: security, migration, x509

This question has been asked on the Oracle Forum as, "How to replace sun.security packages??" (https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2560664), but has not yet received a response.

We have an application that currently makes use of:

```
import sun.security.provider.X509Factory;
import sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId; 
import sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo; 
import sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl; 
import sun.security.x509.CertificateAlgorithmId; 
import sun.security.x509.CertificateValidity; 
import sun.security.x509.CertificateSerialNumber; 
import sun.security.x509.CertificateSubjectName; 
import sun.security.x509.CertificateIssuerName; 
import sun.security.x509.CertificateX509Key; 
import sun.security.x509.CertificateVersion;
```

All of these produce a compile time messages containing: "... internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release"

There are java and javax security packages, but they seem not to contain equivalents for sun.security.x509 & etc..

What should be used to replace the sun.security packages??  And, are there guidelines for the migration?

Comment: Can you please share the link for this question in Oracle forums?

Comment: Added the relevant Oracle Form link, pardon the oversight.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of course is the `java.security.cert` package. If that doesn't meet your requirements I would review them, or have a look at Bouncy Castle.

Answer (score 0):

As of now there are no direct replacment packages from Oracle. If you don't have any plan to run your code in any non sun/oracle jvm this is not an issue. These warnings are meant for highlighting code portability issues with other JVM implementations.

If you want to run the code in other JVM you should use the equivalant libraries provided by that JVM.

I am not sure about what you meant regarding portability , AFAIK (haven't tested, read it somewhere )sun.security is available in jdk1.7 , not sure about availability in upcoming releases.